# Объединить синонимичные метки {“yandex”, “яндекс”}

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Объединить:

- [yandex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex) - 126 вопросов;
- [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81) - 80 вопросов.

(по состоянию на 23.03.2017)

Эти метки нужно объединить, так как ими уже отмечены примерно соразмерные параллельные множества вопросов.