# Привести в порядок метки, ассоциированные с яндексом/yandex

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

Метки [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81) и [yandex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex) уже [синонимизированы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4979/176217), причём в сторону русскоязычной.

Однако, остаётся ряд меток с различным написанием:

- [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81), [яндекс-карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b), [яндекс-танк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%ba), [яндекс-метрика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0), [яндекс-касса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0), [яндекс-директ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82), [рся-яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81), [яндекс-недвижимость](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c), [яндекс-карта-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0-api), [яндекс-алиса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0).

---

- [yandex-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps-api), [yandex-maps-jsapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps-jsapi), [yandexmapkit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandexmapkit), [yandex-metrika-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-metrika-api), [yandex-geocoding-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-geocoding-api), [yandex-translate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-translate), [yandex-places-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-places-api), [yandex-money](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-money), [yandex-maps-embed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps-embed), [yandex-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-api), [yandex-disk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-disk), [yandex-static-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-static-maps-api), [yandexbrowser](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandexbrowser), [yandex-xml](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-xml)

Имхо, следовало бы всё это как-то объединобезобразить или иначе систематизировать и синонимизировать.

Comment: На всякий случай стоит иметь в виду, что на некоторые метки ссылается сам Яндекс https://yandex.ru/dev/commercial/doc/ru/concepts/troubleshooting

Comment: @andreymal при добавлении синонимов ссылки не потеряют свою актуальность в любом случае.

Answer (score 5):

На основании того, что Яндекс всё же в первую очередь российская компания, и для всех упомянутых в вопросе меток существует полноценное описание на русском, с русским же названием служб (по сути - меток); а также по причине того, что наш сайт называет «Stack Overflow на русском», я предлагаю использовать в качестве основных меток именно русскоязычные названия (к тому же это согласуется с принятым ранее [решением](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/37/176217)).

Обеспечивать несмешение кириллицы/латиницы мне кажется не обязательно (это по поводу слова API). Во-первых, можно сделать чисто англоязычные синонимы меток (если их ещё нет). Во-вторых, когда метка уже присутствует в системе, достаточно начать писать и далее уже выбрать подходящую из списка, т.е. переключение раскладки клавиатуры с русского на английский не потребуется при создании вопроса.

- Первый шаг - исправить написание имеющихся меток к виду «компания-технология».
- Второй - синонимизировать к основным русским метках.
- Третий (сложный) - выпилить базовую метку «яндекс», по той же причине, как это [предлагается сделать для «microsoft»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9244/176217).

Comment: Обязательна приписка? Мы же не пишем [tag:microsoft-azure], а просто [tag:azure], например.

Comment: @Suvitruf это про первый пункт из моего списка? Я тут имел в виду, что существующие «yandexbrowser» и «yandexmapkit» надо причесать к виду с дефисом. Если без префикса в виде компании сервис однозначно идентифицируется (имеет самостоятельное имя), то можно рассмотреть и такой вариант, но из имеющегося списка я что-то не могу такого выбрать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ [tag:yandexmarkit] - это не про Яндекс.Маркет. См. описание метки и её использование.

Comment: @Зонтик а кто говорил про "маркет"?

Comment: Я про то, что может лучше не трогать? А то так рука и повернётся сделать синонимами...

Comment: @Зонтик не трогать ЧТО? синоним с ЧЕМ?

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае, я полагаю, невозможно привести метки к единому виду.

На нашем сайте для меток предпочтительно использовать русское написание, если такое имеется. Но вместе с тем, не стоит мешать латиницу и кириллицу в одном слове.

Однако если использовать написание латинскими буквами, то название сервисов Яндекса оказаться не узнаваемым. Примеры:

- [яндекс-касса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0) → [yandex-checkout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-checkout)
- [яндекс-недвижимость](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c) → [yandex-realty](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-realty)
- [яндекс-алиса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0) → [yandex-alice](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-alice)

В то же время применить написание русскими буквами во всех метках не выйдет. Хотя бы потому что до сих пор нет устоявшегося перевода терминов API или XML. А они часто упоминается в обсуждаемых названиях меток.

Итак, моё предложение таково: если в названии метки надо употребить термин, не имеющий перевода на русский язык, то всё название метки должно быть записано латиницей. Иначе — пишем метку кириллицей.

Comment: А почему нельзя смешивать кириллицу и латиницу в названии? К примеру [meta-tag:яндекс-карты-api]?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, мне кажется неудачным, смешение разных письменностей в рамках названия для одной метки

Comment: Не сильно хочу впадать в долгую дискуссию, попробую аргументировать. У вас в тексте англоязычные слова API и XML прекрасно и органично сочетаются с русским текстом. Также и названия меток могут сочетать русскую речь и англоязычные термины для которых нет русского аналога.

Answer (score -1):

Что будет вместо [yandex-maps-jsapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps-jsapi)? [яндекс-карты-jsapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b-jsapi)? Или [яндекс-maps-jsapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-maps-jsapi)? Как по мне, метка должна быть либо полностью на русском, либо полностью на английском.

Но, мне кажется, нужно для начала обсудить корневую метку. Я бы вообще [yandex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex) сделал основной, а не  [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81). А уже потом плясать от этого.

Так что, имхо, для начала нужно создать отдельный вопрос-опросник о том, какую корневую метку делать основной.

Comment: Можно бы попробовать опираться на [официальное название](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps%20/).

Comment: [яндекс-карты-явасценарийпип], естественно

Comment: А почему нельзя смешивать кириллицу и латиницу в названии? К примеру [meta-tag:яндекс-карты-api]?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вам шашечки или ехать?

Comment: @Suvitruf Чего-то я не понял к чему вы клоните. Наоборот, писать "либо полностью на русском, либо полностью на английском" мне больше напоминает "шашечки", то есть какую-то непонятно чем обсулованную догму, лишённую практичности.