# Разве метки [ymaps] и [yandex-maps] не одно и тоже?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Я подозреваю, что эти метки об одном и том же:

- [ymaps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ymaps) (28 вопросов)
- [yandex-maps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps) (18 вопросов)

и, наверное, их надо синонимизировать.

Comment: Одно и то же, как и [яндекс-карты], [яндекс-карта-api], [yandex-maps-api].

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, насчет этих меток было [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9260/507426), и там так и не решили, `карты` или `maps`. А здесь нет проблемы русских/английских названий, просто сокращение `y` от `yandex`.

Comment: Если не решили, надо решать сейчас. Метки явно значат одно и то же, фрагментация вопросов по яндексу сейчас слишком большая. Если вопрос только в выборе основной метки, это можно решить прямым голосованием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объединены [yandex-maps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps) -> [яндекс-карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b)

```
updating post history, 23 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 22 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 22 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'yandex-maps': [yandex-maps] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 374
tag remapping of [яндекс-карты] and [yandex-maps] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym yandex-maps -> яндекс-карты was approved!
```

Синонимизированы [ymaps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ymaps) -> [яндекс-карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b)

Comment: То есть [tag:ymaps] с [tag:яндекс-карты] вы не объединяли, а только синонимизировали?

Comment: @Зонтик именно так.

Comment: [​](https://google.com) А почему?

Comment: @Зонтик потому что я не эксперт в яндекс подсистемах и синоним можно отменить при необходимости. После объединения так уже не получится. Для пользователей разница минимальна.