# Сделать синонимами метки, удалить и переименовать кучу меток на тему яндекса (раз уж решили, что яндексовские метки должны быть на русском)

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки, переименование-метки

#### Вступление

На мете было [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9260/532877), в ходе которого [решили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9263/532877), что метки яндекса должны быть на русском языке.  Здесь я расписал, что и с чем нужно сделать, и почему. Если не согласны с чем-либо — очень прошу вас написать об этом в комментариях, чтобы не допустить ошибок.

#### Синонимы

Довольно часто возникает ситуация, что создаются 2 метки на разных языках. Часть их недавно сделали синонимами ([яндекс-карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b), [yandex-maps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps) и [ymaps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ymaps) например) — спасибо за это модераторам.

Но часть меток так и остались:

- [яндекс-карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b) (409 вопросов), [яндекс-карта-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0-api) (55 вопросов) и [yandex-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps-api) (1475 вопросов). Здесь логично выбрать [яндекс-карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b). Все эти метки явно про api яндекс карт. Выбираем из 2 русских более популярную с более развёрнутым описанием -> [яндекс-карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b).
- [яндекс-метрика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) (38 вопросов, **есть описание**) и [yandex-metrika-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-metrika-api) (44 вопроса, нет описания).
- [яндекс-диск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba) (10 вопросов, **есть описание**) и [yandex-disk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-disk) (24 вопроса, нет описания).
- [яндекс-облако](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be) (3 вопроса, **есть описание**) и [yandex-cloud](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-cloud) (19 вопросов, нет описания).

Их нужна сделать синонимами (в сторону русских, как и решили).

#### Метки на удаление

Ещё есть метки, которые надо сжечь:

- [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81) (550 вопросов) — [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be).  Сжечь надо, ибо [google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) сожгли на enSO, а  у нас [запланировали много лет назад сжечь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320/). С яндексом та же песня.
- [yandex-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-api) (38 вопросов) — [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be). Практически то же, что и [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81).

#### Метки на переименование

- [поисковик-яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81) -> [яндекс-поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba) — [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be). Проблема: само название кривое и не соответствует официальному.
- [yandex-translate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-translate) (24 вопроса) -> [яндекс-переводчик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba)  — [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be). Нужно переименовать, чтобы метка была на русском.
- [yandex-money](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-money) (17 вопросов) -> [яндекс-деньги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d0%b3%d0%b8). Тоже самое, что и с [yandex-translate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-translate).

Comment: В дополнение: недавно созданную [tag:поисковик-яндекс] переименовать в [яндекс-поиск]. Это можно и вручную, пока не наплодили вопросов.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight вы не первый, кто мне это говорит (метку я создал). Да, название не самое удачное... Но вручную и так куча всего делать приходится, поэтому лучше автоматически.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight добавил в список на переименование.

Comment: Нашел еще ошибку: yandexmapkit не должен быть синонимом яндекс-маркет. Это про другую библиотеку.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight глянул описание (как я его раньше не заметил - вопрос) и убрал из списка.

Comment: скрипт что ли написать для переименовывания... а то программисты - а всё вручную ;)

Comment: @wchistow вы как раз с SE API разбираетесь. Может, напишите :)

Comment: @Зонтик, получилось! эту правку сделала моя программа - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1320604/6

Comment: Правда, после неё вопрос отформатирован с помощью html, а не markdown, но показывается всё так же как и раньше.

Comment: @wchistow Подождите с программными правками. Переименование отлично делается встроенными средствами (объединение меток), без поднятия вопросов. Плюс сама полезность сих действий невелика, вполне можно пользоваться английским написанием для этих малозначимых меток.

Answer (score 3):

Насчет Яндекс.Карт - да, это нужно сделать, и как можно скорее. Когда-то на сайте Reni отвечала, она по уму расставляла метки на вопросах: общую [yandex-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps-api) и узкоспециализированные вроде [yandex-maps-jsapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps-jsapi), [yandex-maps-embed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps-embed) и др. Затем, когда она прекратила активность, метки стали расставлять как попало. Сейчас уже очень большие множества вопросов по одной теме выросли в разных метках. Эту проблему надо решать, так как пользователям сейчас трудно будет разобраться, какие метки ставить на вопросы и на какие подписываться.

Предлагаю приоритетно создать синонимы: [яндекс-карта-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0-api), [yandex-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps-api) -> [яндекс-карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b). Так как у нас сайт про программирование, вопросы по простому использованию карт не входят в тематику, эти метки представляют собой одно и то же. Встраивание в сайт блока с картой также относится к использованию API, так как там внутри обращение к тем же серверам. Модераторам просьба, если этот ответ заплюсуют, создайте синонимы, либо напишите свои возражения здесь в комментариях.