# Как попросить модераторов синонимизировать метки, если предложение о синонимизации было одобрено сообществом, но не было реализовано?

Tags: поддержка, синонимы-меток, модерация, тревоги, мета

Есть [предложение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13068/532877) по синонимизации и переименованию меток. Оно одобрено сообществом (+6/-1), никаких *возражений* кроме *безымянного необъяснённого минуса* нет. Посту уже 2 недели.

То есть решение принято. Сделать метки синонимами безпрепятственно могут только модераторы. Поэтому я решил нажать <kbd>тревога</kbd> -> <kbd>требуется вмешательство модератора</kbd> и попросил модератора привести решение в жизнь. При этом я подробно описал ситуацию.

Тревога повисела так несколько дней, а потом её отклонили:

[image: Отклонённая тревога]

Вопрос: а как тогда приводить решение в силу? Как позвать модераторов?

Comment: +6 - вообще не тянет на "одобрено сообществом". Скорее сообществу все равно.

Comment: или сообщество у нас из восьми участников  ¯_(ツ)_/¯ (6+ 1-  "имодератор, которому все равно" )

Comment: Модераторы не обязаны действовать по решению на мете, поэтому просто "позвать и сказать делайте" конечно нельзя. Можно убеждать, что это дело важное и молиться, что кто-то обратит на это внимание. Вы уже знаете по "Ритуалу массового сожжения", что предложения могут годами лежать нереализованными. Я попробую позже в той теме написать свой ответ, добавлю аргументов.

Comment: @Grundy для нашей меты +6 для предложении о синонимах - это очень даже неплохо.

Comment: @Зонтик, не, это так не работает. Действительно важные вопросы собирают много, в данном случае, очевидно, тема вообще не интересна сообществу

Comment: @Grundy "Действительно важные вопросы" - например [снятие Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12267/240512)? :)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight на счёт ритуала - это сжигание меток, оно не автоматизировано, поэтому и лежит годами.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, там нет голосования за снятие :) Но хотя бы количество голосов более-менее, хотя бы более 45-50 нужно

Comment: @Grundy но надеюсь для утверждения очевидных синонимов не нужно 40-45 голосов?

Comment: @Зонтик, для утверждения синонима достаточно 5 человек, которые за этот синоним проголосовали. А не вопрос на мете.

Comment: @Grundy ага. Только для голосования нужно 5 баллов по метке.

Comment: @Зонтик, не вижу никакой проблемы с этим