# Запретить [яндекс]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, чёрный-список-меток

#### Вступление

Не так давно была [выпилена метка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13068/532877) [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81) с её синонимом [yandex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex). С меткой-оригиналом было больше 550 вопросов, а если учесть, что была ещё одна похожая метка [yandex-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-api), то количество вопросов было близко к 600.

#### Почему метка не должна существовать и должна быть запрещена

- У Яндекса очень много сервисов и API, метка неодназначна и не может быть полезна. По этой же причине на enSO сожгли `[google]`, а у нас [google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) [запланировали сжечь много лет назад](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320/532877).
- Вместо конкретных меток (например [яндекс-карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b), [яндекс-поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba), [яндекс-диск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba) и так далее) вешают [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81). Из-за этого затрудняется поиск, а это для меток задача №1. Можно сделать вывод, что метка не просто бесполезна, а ещё и несёт вред.
- Так как вопросов с ней было не так уж и мало, и высока вероятность, что её создадут снова, её стоит запретить (внести в чёрный список).

#### Всплывающая подсказка о запрете

Если метка запрещается, то у неё высвечивается подсказка, почему она была запрещена. Сначала просто факт запрета, он для всех меток един:

> Метка [название-метки] запрещена.

А потом уже конкретное предупреждение для конкретной метки. Для нашего случая я предлагаю такое:

> У компании Яндекс много различных сервисов, поэтому стоит выбирать более конкретные метки: [яндекс-карты], [яндекс-поиск], [яндекс-диск] и так далее.

#### На что я ещё хотел бы обратить внимание

Запретить надо не только [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81), но и [синоним](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13068/532877) [yandex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex), а так же идентичную по смыслу [yandex-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-api).

Comment: И тоже самое сделать с [tag:google] когда и его сожгут.

Comment: @чистов_n когда гугл сожгут, я сделаю про него отдельный пост.

Comment: Как-то неправильно звучит "С меткой-оригиналом"... Может, лучше "В метке-оригинале"? Я мог бы и сам поправить, но вам виднее)

Comment: И кстати, [яндекс-api] тоже надо запретить)

Comment: @Глеб всё верно. На вопросы вешаются метки, то есть вопросы ***С*** меткой. Вот на форумах вопросы *в какой-то ветке*, так как там используется система, где вопрос задаётся в каком-то разделе (ветке)

Comment: @Зонтик, гугл сожгли, пора делать пост.

Comment: @wchistow [tag:google-api] оставили... Т.е тоже самое.

Answer (score 5):

Метки [yandex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex), [yandex-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-api) и [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81) теперь запрещены на ru.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNccR.png): *" Яндекс много разных сервисов, поэтому выбирайте что-то более конкретное."* - there miss a word "имеет": "Яндекс имеет много разных сервисов, поэтому выбирайте что-то более конкретное".

Comment: @Зонтик additionally it's not clear why do we have first sentence `Метка [яндекс] запрещена.` twice.

Comment: Both of the issues listed in comments above should be resolved now.